# Select the lastest N day data from table

Tags: sql

price date        time
    1.0   20100815      1
    1.2   20100815      2 
    1.3   20100815      3
    2     20100814      1
    3.1   20100813      1
    3.2   20100813      2
    :
    :
    :

Now I want to select the latest 3 days price with all the time, I use like this

```
select price, date from allquotes where date in 
      (select date from allquotes group by date order by date desc limit 3)
```

Is this right? Is this efficient?
Any suggestion to improve this?

If I would like to show only one price with the latest time, how to do that?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Which price do you want to win when there are duplicates for the same date, or do you want to show all of them?

Comment: Any particular flavour of SQL?

Comment: How big this table could be? Which database you use? You will hit a full table scan, group operation followed by sort operation. It is right, it might be efficient, but all depends on my first two questions.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick on SQL Server:

```
select top 3 q.pricee, q.date, q.time
from (
    select date, max(time) as MaxTime
    from allquotes
    group by date
) qm
inner join quotes q on qm.date = q.date and qm.MaxTime = time
order by date desc
```

For MySQL, try:

```
select q.pricee, q.date, q.time
from (
    select date, max(time) as MaxTime
    from allquotes
    group by date
) qm
inner join quotes q on qm.date = q.date and qm.MaxTime = time
order by date desc
limit 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Top 3 Sum(price),
             date,
             Sum(time)
From   allquotes
Group By date
Order By date Desc
```